# Angular:How to reuse service across different controller and module

Tags: angularjs

suppose i have service in angular and tell me how could i reuse that service across different controller and module. see the code

code taken from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="CalculatorController">
        Enter a number:
        <input type="number" ng-model="number" />
        <button ng-click="doSquare()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
        <button ng-click="doCube()">X<sup>3</sup></button>

        <div>Answer: {{answer}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('MathService', function() {
    this.add = function(a, b) { return a + b };

    this.subtract = function(a, b) { return a - b };

    this.multiply = function(a, b) { return a * b };

    this.divide = function(a, b) { return a / b };
});

app.service('CalculatorService', function(MathService){

    this.square = function(a) { return MathService.multiply(a,a); };
    this.cube = function(a) { return MathService.multiply(a, MathService.multiply(a,a)); };

});

app.controller('CalculatorController', function($scope, CalculatorService) {

    $scope.doSquare = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.square($scope.number);
    }

    $scope.doCube = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.cube($scope.number);
    }
});
```

the service has been declare and attached with app module. now tell me if i need to use this same service in another module call app1 then do i need to define and attach the same service there in app1 module ?

looking for guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the same service accross different *controllers* in the same module, you can just do so.

But, if you want to use the same service accross different *modules*, then you need to include the module in which the service is registered, into the module in which you want to reuse the service. In fact, it might be better to put the service in some kind of reusable module:

```
var reusableModule = angular.module('reusable', []);    

reusableModule.service('MathService', function() {
    this.add = function(a, b) { return a + b };

    this.subtract = function(a, b) { return a - b };

    this.multiply = function(a, b) { return a * b };

    this.divide = function(a, b) { return a / b };
});

reusableModule.service('CalculatorService', function(MathService){

    this.square = function(a) { return MathService.multiply(a,a); };
    this.cube = function(a) { return MathService.multiply(a, MathService.multiply(a,a)); };

});

//now use the reusable module in your app module
var app = angular.module('app', ['reusable']);
app.controller('CalculatorController', function($scope, CalculatorService) {

    $scope.doSquare = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.square($scope.number);
    }

    $scope.doCube = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.cube($scope.number);
    }
});
```

and the same for app1:

```
var app1 = angular.module('app1', ['reusable']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the 'app' module from 'app1' and then inject it just like you did in the controller and CalculatorService.

```
var app1 = angular.module('app1', ['app']);

app1.controller('App1Controller', function ($scope, MathService, CalculatorService) {

});
```